# Why is $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{{\sin}^2 x \, dx}{5+3 \cos x}= \frac{i}{2} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{z^2(3z^2+10z+3)} \, dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In a solved exercise, the textbook I'm reading states $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{{\sin}^2 x \, dx}{5+3 \cos x}= \frac{i}{2} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{(z^2-1)^2}{z^2(3z^2+10z+3)} \, dz$ ?$ without offering any explanation. Why is this equality obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rewrite all of your trig functions as exponential functions.

$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x\\
\cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\\
\sin x = \frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

Then substitute $z = e^{ix}, dx = \frac {1}{iz} \ dz$

As $x$ ranges from zero to $2\pi, z$ will trace out the unit cicle.

$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac {(\frac {z - z^{-1}}{2i})^2}{iz(5+\frac {3z + 3z^{-1}}{2})} \ dz$

Which simplifies to what you show above.